# Can't display png

Tags: r, x11, xserver, shiny

I'm running R-shiny (R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)) on a VM (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4). Everything works, i.e., server starts up, and application runs etc... as long as I don't try to plot a graph

```
renderPlot
```

I then see on the main panel a message [error : unable to start device png].  I would post my whole code but this problem I think has to do with rendering plots as when I use 
    renderText 
and spit out some data it works just fine.

Actually when I just type in 
    png() 
in R I get this error
[
Error in .External2(C_X11, paste("png::", filename, sep = ""), g$width,  : 
  unable to start device PNG
In addition: Warning message:
In png() : unable to open connection to X11 display ''
]
of course if I forward via ssh -X to my mac, I can type in **png()** no problem and plot data etc...

-A few more things to note, when I type in capabilties() I find the only things that are false are jpeg, tiff, X11, aqua, and profmem (so png and cairo are True)

-I've installed libpng, cairo, and libX11, libX11-devel, libXt, libXt-devel before building R from source

I'm guessing my problem is that I need to have X server running. In addition the DISPLAY variable is null.

So, I guess when it boils down to it my question is ... assuming my logic is correct.

1) Do I need to run / start X server [ currently it terminates after starting for some reason] or can I just set the DISPLAY variable?

2) If I can just set my DISPLAY variable what should I set it to (localhost:0.0 hasn't worked)

Obviously if there is something I'm missing these questions may be irrelevant.

Thanks in advance and sorry for rambling, wanted to be thorough.

PJ

Comment: The `DISPLAY` variable should point to a working X server, otherwise there's very little sense in setting it.

Comment: May point you in the right direction: http://trestletechnology.net/2013/02/graphical-tools-rgl-on-a-headless-shiny-server/

Answer (score 15):

Does it help if you set `option(bitmapType = 'cairo')`? I have been skeptical about how R chooses the bitmap device type using `.Call(C_cairoProps, 2L)` in `grDevices:::.onLoad()` (this might be a bug, but I cannot say it for sure).

The option `bitmapType` falls back to `Xlib` if the test of `cairo` fails, thus giving you a cryptic error message about `X11`. Note the `type` argument in `png()`:

```
> args(png)
function (filename = "Rplot%03d.png", width = 480, height = 480, 
    units = "px", pointsize = 12, bg = "white", res = NA, ..., 
    type = c("cairo", "cairo-png", "Xlib", "quartz"), antialias)
```

The default value of this argument is `getOption('bitmapType')`, and in your case it is `Xlib` due to the test in `grDevices:::.onLoad()`. If you are 100% sure that `cairo` works, you can change this option, say, in your `~/.Rprofile`.

Comment: Hello Yihui. Do you suggest to set `option(bitmapType='cairo')` in the `server.R` file ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent yes, that is also one way to go; I mentioned `~/.Rprofile` above, which means to set this option globally for all your R sessions

Comment: I have tried `options(bitmapType='cairo')` in the `server.R` file but that does not change anything.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent you mean exactly the same error message? can you simply test `png(tempfile(), type='cairo'); dev.off()`?

Comment: Yes exactly the same error message. Do you mean typing this line as a command line ? (I'll try tomorrow, I'm at home now)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Yes, type the code as a command line in an R terminal. The same error message indicates the option was not respected, so I ask you to hardcode the option and see if it works.

Comment: Yihu, my colleague (Linux server admin) has recompiled R-3.0.1 with cairo, and now everything works well with `options(bitmapType='cairo')` ! Thank you !

Comment: I had to add `options(bitmapType='cairo')` to my `~/.Rprofile`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this by installing a few additional development packages and then uninstalling/reinstalling R from source.  All the other recommended options did not work for me until this.

```
sudo yum install pango-devel pango libpng-devel
```

Go to directory where source R file was installed:

```
make uninstall
./configure --with-readline=no (or ./configure might work for you)
make
make install
```