# r graphs in jupyter - unable to start png() device

Tags: r, png, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I am using R in Jupyter, but unable to plot graphs in the notebook itself.

Here is a reproducible example

```
set.seed(123)
mat = as.matrix(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
plot(mat)
```

**In Jupyter:**

```
Error in png(tf, width, height, "in", pointsize, bg, res, antialias = antialias): unable to start png() device
Traceback:
```

If I use following, I can save the image in *png* format in current working directory.

```
png('test.png')
plot(mat)
dev.off()
```

Edit:

```
SessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 16299)
```

I have gone through following but none of them solve my problem.

1. [Displaying ggplot2 graphs from R in Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30920380/displaying-ggplot2-graphs-from-r-in-jupyter)
2. [unable to plot in jupyter notebook using R kernel](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/210)
3. [libXrender.so.1 is required to display R plots inline](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/54)
4. [Can't display png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243648/cant-display-png?rq=1)
5. [Rendering of graphs in R kernel Notebooks on GitHub](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/145) (relevant to Github)

Comment: since I could not got this to work, I shifted to R markdown which is easier to work with R studio and provides a lot more flexibility. I am kind of grateful that I did not get any answer in time. My first preference is still Python and Jupyter, but if I have to code and present in R, I prefer R markdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue. I closed Anaconda, opened it again and then updated the kernel; Finally, it worked again without any error.

```
conda install -c r r-essentials
```

Comment: I have changed my laptop, so for me there is no way to know if that is the right answer. Today I installed miniconda and IRkernel and my code seems to work. So I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the kernel worked fine with me.

Comment: Just add my two cents:
Actually worked for me. My guess is that I've used the png() and dev.off() function before and it might have messed with some config